# Vuetify Datables - expanded-item slot transition

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify Datatables and I would like to use a transition on the expanded template. Is there any possibility to use the Vuetify Transition on `v-slot:v-slot:expanded-item`?

I wasn't able to make the transition work.

Here is my code:

```
       <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
            <td :colspan="headers.length">
                <p>ID Transakce: {{ item.transactionId }}
                <p>Stav {{ item.transactionData.state }}</p>
                <p>Podstav {{ item.transactionData.subState }}</p>
            </td>
    </template>
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: `<slot>` is not a DOM node - so you can not apply a transition on it. The transition must be applied on the parent node - which obviously sits inside the Vuetify code. A workaround is to wrap the slot content inside a `<transition>` and add `v-show` on the appropriate nodes inside the transition which you will have to manually toggle synchronously with the row expanding/collapsing.

Comment: @IVOGELOV In my case the parent node is `v-data-table`. Should I use the transition on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transition on `expanded-item` was removed for 2.x version. There are some issues open [on github](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8197) to to bring its back.

By the way there is a tricky solution posted on codepen: https://codepen.io/webifi/pen/ExxmXbJ

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I think I will have to use that tricky solution or use a `dialog` to show the data.